# Font Rendering between Mozilla and webkit

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, safari, rendering

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the recent Safari update, but I'm beginning to notice this a lot. There is a drastic difference in the way each browser is rendering fonts.

for instance, I took screenshots of what I am seeing here on stackoverflow...
http://twitpic.com/q43eh

I have verified that this is a trend via my co-workers machines.

has anyone noticed this or have any thoughts on non-hack solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Font rendering isn't specified anywhere in the standards and therefore may (and will) vary between browsers and platforms.

In particular, Safari on Windows renders fonts like OS X does which tends to look weird to Windows users as Windows [has quite a different take on how to render fonts than OS X](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000885.html).

Comment: thanks for the article! This issue wasn't as apparent to me until a recent project which had some stacked elements and there was such a large variation between the browsers. I've always been aware rendering issues, it just recently seems to be more drastic. There is a 30 px difference in height of the containers on the linked image. I've been writing markup for close to 10 years now, and I felt surprise and put-off when this became apparent to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely notice this, especially if you use Expression Web SuperPreview. This is just a general problem of the web, just like folks can hit Ctrl-+ and make your text bigger. Try not to use many absolute coordinates in CSS and the layout engine will ensure it's still readable

Answer (score 0):

I first noticed this in OSX in October 2010. It is especially noticeable with Helvetica Neue. I suspect that an OSX update broke font anti-aliasing in font sizes above 12 pixels. I've posted an Apple Support message [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=12752802&tstart=0).